# Invalid column name when using EF Core filtered includes

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-5.0

I came across this error when modifying a DB first project (using fluent migrator) and scaffolding the EF context to generate models. I have reproduced it by making a code-first simplification. This means that *I can't accept answers that suggest modifying the annotations or fluent configuration*, because this will be deleted and recreated on the next migration and scaffold.

The simplified idea is that a device has:

- many attributes
- many histories representing changes to the device over time

  - each history entry has an optional location

IOW you can move a device around to locations (or no location) and keep track of that over time.
[image]

The code-first model I came up with to simulate this is as follows:

```
public class ApiContext : DbContext
{
    public ApiContext(DbContextOptions<ApiContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<History> Histories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    public List<History> Histories { get; } = new List<History>();
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; } = new List<Attribute>();
}

public class History
{
    public int HistoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; }

    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }

    public List<History> Histories { get; } = new List<History>();
}
```

Running the following query to select all devices works fine. I'm using a [filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) to only select the most recent history for this "view":

```
var devices = _apiContext.Devices.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(d => d.Histories.OrderByDescending(h => h.DateFrom).Take(1))
    .ThenInclude(h => h.Location)
    .Include(d => d.Attributes)
    .Select(d => d.ToModel()).ToList();
```

that works fine, however when I try and select only one device by ID using the same includes:

```
var device = _apiContext.Devices.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(d => d.Histories.OrderByDescending(h => h.DateFrom).Take(1))
    .ThenInclude(h => h.Location)
    .Include(d => d.Attributes)
    .First(d => d.DeviceId == deviceId)
    .ToModel();
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'LocationId'.
Invalid column name 'HistoryId'.
Invalid column name 'DateFrom'.
Invalid column name 'LocationId'.
Invalid column name 'State'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at efcore_test.App.PrintSingleDevice(Int32 deviceId) in C:\Users\Iain\projects\efcore-5-bug\efcore-test\App.cs:line 44
   at efcore_test.Program.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Main>b__4(App app) in C:\Users\Iain\projects\efcore-5-bug\efcore-test\Program.cs:line 28
   at efcore_test.Program.RunInScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Action`1 method) in C:\Users\Iain\projects\efcore-5-bug\efcore-test\Program.cs:line 35
   at efcore_test.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Iain\projects\efcore-5-bug\efcore-test\Program.cs:line 28
ClientConnectionId:1418edb2-0889-4f4d-9554-85344c9a35a9
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16
```

I can't figure out why this is working for a number of rows but not working for a single row.

For completeness, `ToModel()` is just an extension method to return a POCO.

I'm not even sure where to start looking, ideas welcome!

*Edit*

- bug report: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26585
- repro: https://github.com/thinkOfaNumber/efcore-5-test

Comment: The difference is that in the first query the Includes are ignored because `ToModel()` is a projection directly on the `IQueryable` which ignores the Includes. The second query executes the `IQueryable` and then does the projection in memory. That said, this may be a bug. In EF-core 5, I can execute a simpler query containing `Include` with `OrderByDescending` and `Take(1)` without any problems. What if you try queries with the only one of the Includes per query? Maybe it's a mapping error.

Comment: The first thing you have to check is if the first query really works w/o `.Select(d => d.ToModel())`.

Comment: Oh, what I said about ignored `Include`s isn't true. It could be if `ToModel` was an extension method like AutoMapper's `ProjectTo`, but it's a method inside the expression (`.Select(d => d.ToModel())`), so EF does execute the entire query and then executes the projection client-side because it's in the final select. In fact this answers Ivan's suggestion: it doesn't work. Would be interesting to see which Includes do and don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** The bug is fixed in EF Core 6.0, so the next applies to EF Core 5.0 only.

Looks like you have hit EF Core 5.0 query translation bug, so I would suggest to seek/report it to EF Core GitHub issue tracker.

From what I can tell, it's caused by "pushing down" the root query as subquery because of the `Take` operator (which is basically what `First` method is using in the second case). This somehow messes up the generated subquery aliases and leads to invalid SQL.

It can be seen by comparing the generated SQL for the first query

```sql
SELECT [d].[DeviceId], [d].[DeviceName], [t0].[HistoryId], [t0].[DateFrom], [t0].[DeviceId], [t0].[LocationId], [t0].[State], [t0].[LocationId0], [t0].[LocationName], [a].[AttributeId], [a].[DeviceId], [a].[Name]
FROM [Devices] AS [d]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT [t].[HistoryId], [t].[DateFrom], [t].[DeviceId], [t].[LocationId], [t].[State], [l].[LocationId] AS [LocationId0], [l].[LocationName]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP(1) [h].[HistoryId], [h].[DateFrom], [h].[DeviceId], [h].[LocationId], [h].[State]
        FROM [Histories] AS [h]
        WHERE [d].[DeviceId] = [h].[DeviceId]
        ORDER BY [h].[DateFrom] DESC
    ) AS [t]
    LEFT JOIN [Locations] AS [l] ON [t].[LocationId] = [l].[LocationId]
) AS [t0]
LEFT JOIN [Attribute] AS [a] ON [d].[DeviceId] = [a].[DeviceId]
ORDER BY [d].[DeviceId], [t0].[DateFrom] DESC, [t0].[HistoryId], [t0].[LocationId0], [a].[AttributeId]
```

and for the second (or just inserting `.Where(d => d.DeviceId == deviceId).Take(1)` before `Select` in the first):

```sql
SELECT [t].[DeviceId], [t].[DeviceName], [t1].[HistoryId], [t1].[DateFrom], [t1].[DeviceId], [t1].[LocationId], [t1].[State], [t1].[LocationId0], [t1].[LocationName], [a].[AttributeId], [a].[DeviceId], [a].[Name]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [d].[DeviceId], [d].[DeviceName]
    FROM [Devices] AS [d]
    WHERE [d].[DeviceId] = @__deviceId_0
) AS [t]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT [t].[HistoryId], [t].[DateFrom], [t].[DeviceId], [t].[LocationId], [t].[State], [l].[LocationId] AS [LocationId0], [l].[LocationName]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP(1) [h].[HistoryId], [h].[DateFrom], [h].[DeviceId], [h].[LocationId], [h].[State]
        FROM [Histories] AS [h]
        WHERE [t].[DeviceId] = [h].[DeviceId]
        ORDER BY [h].[DateFrom] DESC
    ) AS [t0]
    LEFT JOIN [Locations] AS [l] ON [t].[LocationId] = [l].[LocationId]
) AS [t1]
LEFT JOIN [Attribute] AS [a] ON [t].[DeviceId] = [a].[DeviceId]
ORDER BY [t].[DeviceId], [t1].[DateFrom] DESC, [t1].[HistoryId], [t1].[LocationId0], [a].[AttributeId]
```

Note the usage of `[t]` in the first `SELECT [t].[HistoryId]...` inside the `OUTER APPLY`, which in the fist query is alias to the inner `Histories` subquery in `FROM` clause, while in second it is alias to the outer `Devices` subquery, which of couse have no columns mentioned in the error message. Apparently in the second case `[t0]` should have been used.

Since it is a bug, you have to wait it to be fixed. Until then, the workaround I could suggest is to explicitly execute row limiting operator (`First`) outside of the EF Core query context, e.g.

```cs
var device = _apiContext.Devices.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(d => d.Histories.OrderByDescending(h => h.DateFrom).Take(1))
    .ThenInclude(h => h.Location)
    .Include(d => d.Attributes)
    .Where(d => d.DeviceId == deviceId) // instead of .First(d => d.DeviceId == deviceId)
    .AsEnumerable() // switch to client evaluation (LINQ to Objects context)
    .First() // and execute `First` here
    .ToModel();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but won't that workaround load everything into memory first? I can't do that as the table is too large, so I might have to try a few versions and see if the bug has been there for all of v5 (I just upgraded from ef-core 3 to use filtered includes!).
It's late here now so I will get to the issue tracker tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will load, but not everything. Note that the `Where` filter is still applied server side (before switching to client side evaluation with `AsEnumerable()`), hence only items matching the filter will be loaded.  Which for PK value filter like in the question would be a 0 or 1 item - exactly the same as if `First` is executed directly. It would be an issue if you want to apply paging to the first query (before `ToList()`), since the `Take` must be after `AsEnumerable` in order to workaround the current EF Core bug.

Comment: As of when it was introduced, I can't say exactly, but I duplicated it in the latest official EF Core 5.0.11, so there is a chance it to appear even in the incoming EFC 6.0

Comment: As luck would have it I ran into a similar issue today, but I can't isolate what exactly is causing it: it works correctly in a live API, it works correctly in a unit test for the API, but fails in an isolated unit test for just the query.  The strange thing is if I view the 'Debug' view for the query, the SQL it has generated is correct, but the moment you execute the query (First() for example), it ends up as something else

Comment: Of course, that is an acceptable workaround then, thanks @IvanStoev, upgrading this from like to answer!

Comment: @John `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` and similar *final* query operators - they modify the generated query before executing it. Basically appending `Take(1)` at the end. `Take` is the operator which is causing invalid SQL generation in this case.

Comment: @IvanStoev - you're right: if I add a step for `Take(1)`, that's when my issue appears as well