# Error with skip and take in child entity using projection with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-sql, projection

I have this query below and I'm getting these 2 errors from the Members property

> Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Infrastructure.Data.DataContext'.

> Invalid column name 'UserId'
> Invalid column name 'Status'

If I remove the Skip() and Take() the query will run!
If I remove the .select() projection the query will run!

I tried placing the skip/take before the .select() but it still gave me the error.

I also tried removing .ToList(), but still got the error as well.

```
var yogabandTest = await _dbContext.Yogabands
.Select(p => new
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name,
    HostId = p.HostId,
    MemberCount = p.Members.Count(),
    Members = p.Members
        .Where(p => p.Status == YogabandMemberStatus.Active)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.Status)
        .Select(p => new {
            Id = p.User.Id,
            Name = p.User.UserName,
        })
        .Skip(0)
        .Take(1)
        .ToList()    
})
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Name == pageParams.YogabandName && p.HostId == hostId);
```

**UPDATE** - I've rewritten the query with an .Include() using this [MS link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#load-related-entities-eagerly-when-possible) and now the query runs, BUT it doesn't Take() the number I provide ex. (2). It just returns all rows (5) in the .Members result.

```
var yogabandTest = await _dbContext.Yogabands
            .Include(
                yogaband => yogaband.Members
                    .Where(member => member.Status == YogabandMemberStatus.Active)
                    .OrderByDescending(member => member.Status)
                    .Skip(0)
                    .Take(2)
            )
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                HostId = p.HostId,
                Members = p.Members
                    .Select(p => new {
                        Id = p.User.Id,
                        Name = p.User.UserName
                    })
                    
            })
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Name == pageParams.YogabandName && p.HostId == hostId);
```

Comment: what happens if you temporarily hard code in some values for the Skip & Take?

Comment: ya I tried that, still get the error.

Comment: This sounds very similar to the something I've answered yesterday - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69880136/invalid-column-name-when-using-ef-core-filtered-includes/69883517#69883517. Most likely the exact same bug. Try replacing the final `FirstOrDefaultAsync` call with `Where` + client eval (the suggested workaround there), e.g. `(await _dbContext.Yogabands.Select(...).Where(p => p.Name == pageParams.YogabandName && p.HostId == hostId).ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Hi Ivan. Can you put this into an answer as I think there might be a syntax error with what you wrote. It's at the end ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @user1186050 I can't, because I haven't verified it. Also, if my guess it correct, then I'm supposed to mark this as duplicate instead of answering it. I'm just leaving the decision to you. Without async, it would have been exactly as in the other post - `query.Where(...).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()`. With async and w/o additional packages it should be `(await query.Where(...).ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault()`, i.e. needs to await `ToListAsync()` (hence enclosed in parenthesis) before calling `FirstOrDefault()` or similar.

Comment: @user1186050 It's the same EF Core 5.0 bug (verified). And is fixed in EF Core 6.0 (just released), so if you can upgrade... Just note that it requires net6, thus VS2022.

Comment: What about VS Code? I'm not using VS.